# Why call presentViewController in the end of custom segue, it cause viewDidAppear to be called twice?

Tags: ios, view, call, viewwillappear

In my UIStoryboardSegue subclass, I use presentViewController at the end of the perform method, this cause viewDidAppear/viewWillAppear to be called twice?

How can I prevent this?

Thanks

Current code:

```
override func perform() {

    // Assign the source and destination views to local variables
    let sourceView = sourceViewController.view as UIView!
    let destView = destinationViewController.view as UIView!

    // Get the screen width and height
    let screenWidth = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width
    let screenHeight = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height

    // Specify the initial position of the destination view
    destView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, screenHeight, screenWidth, screenHeight)

    // Add the destination view to the window
    let window = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow
    window?.insertSubview(destView, aboveSubview: sourceView)

    // Animate the transition
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.7, animations: { () -> Void in

        // Scale down the source view
        sourceView.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(sourceView.transform, 0.90, 0.90)

        }) { (Finished) -> Void in
    }

    UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, delay: 0.2, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.6, initialSpringVelocity: 0.7, options: .CurveEaseOut, animations: { () -> Void in

        destView.frame = CGRectOffset(destView.frame, 0.0, -screenHeight)

        }) { (finished) -> Void in

            self.sourceViewController.presentViewController(self.destinationViewController as UIViewController, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

I see now that without presentViewController the new controller is destroyed soon after the animation custom segue. I see why we need it.

Comment: when you add print("\(unsafeAddressOf(self))") in your viewDidAppear of the destination-VC, does this print out the same address?

Comment: Yes (And cool). Tried it 3 times.

Comment: ok, will run the appcoda code now and will edit my answer then

Answer (score 0):

The reason why viewDidAppear gets called twice is that you first insert the viewcontroller as a subview into the keyWindow. (which triggers the viewDidAppear)
[image]

and then present the viewcontroller. (which triggers the viewDidAppear also)
[image]

This brings also some side effects to your app because you will end up with a viewHierachy like:

```
-- KeyWindow
---- FirstVC View
---- SecondVC View
---- UITransitionView (because of the presentVC)
------- SecondVC View
```

If you want to achieve this swipe/scroll transition why not just use a scrollView and have childviewcontrollers in it?

The other solution for this would be to use a custom transition and simply call presentViewController with a custom transition as described here: http://www.raywenderlich.com/113845/ios-animation-tutorial-custom-view-controller-presentation-transitions

Comment: OK, thanks. But why a respectable sites do this in their tutorials? They put presentViewController in the end of the perform method?

Comment: @Shay you could not be any more unspecific ^^ please tell use the site so we can check for our own.

Comment: can you please provide a link? Maybe I get your question wrong :)

Comment: Just tried in my code with out presentViewController and without dismissViewControllerAnimated in the unwind custom segue. It crashed. We need the presentViewController for this.

Comment: Add code and important comment. Also tested appcoda code, same results.

Comment: Thanks christian, check the other animation, you can't do it with scroll view as you know. Also I have more great animation transition so, this custom segue technic is superb. Thanks for the link, I need a solid way to achieve all the animation I did using the custom segue.

Comment: I would recommend to do the first animation via a scrollView as the user also has a better experience then for this transition.

For the second animation you can achieve this with a custom presentation transition, why not do so? :)

Comment: Custom presentation transition? You mean using the link you provided? If yes, so, I have the book, didn't reached to that chapter yet, going to read it now.